# How to disable internal Wi-Fi hardware and use Wi-Fi from USB adapter?

Tags: command-line, bash, permissions, 17.04, chmod

I'm Using Ubuntu 17.04 on an old LG laptop. My goal is to disable the internal Wi-Fi (since it is old and slow), and use my USB Wi-Fi adapter to obtain better Wi-Fi. However, some errors occur when I'm trying to install the drivers from Edimax's site:

Following the instructions from the `readme.txt` file to run the `install.sh` file failed due to file permissions. I tried giving executable permissions to the entire directory using:

```
sudo chmod +X *
```

which gave most files/directories executable permissions, but not to `install.sh`.

[image: ls -l output showing permissions of files]

Even after trying to give permissions only to the specific file I had no luck.

Here is the output of `lsusb`:

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 7392:7811 Edimax Technology Co., Ltd EW-7811Un 802.11n Wireless Adapter [Realtek RTL8188CUS]
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

And `uname -r` shows `4.10.0-28-generic`.

1. Why can't I change the permissions of that file?
2. How to disable the internal Wi-Fi?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please check to see if two possibly conflicting drivers are loaded:

```
lsmod | grep rtl
```

If you find that both rtl8192cu and rtl8xxxu are loaded, then blacklist one:

```
sudo -i
echo "blacklist rtl8192cu"  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
exit
```

You will also need a change to Network Manager:

```
sudo nano /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
```

Add a new section as follows:

```
[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
```

Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor.

After making these changes, reboot and let us hear the result.

Comment: possible to conflict latop's internal wifi module ?

Comment: Most certainly. Why not just use the internal??

Comment: hi, firstly - it WORKS !!! ( I'll be happy to understand what you did ),
secondly- since it is an old laptop ( 10 year or so ), its wifi  is 802g and very slow, and sometime disconnects  when I used it as a windwos machine( i guess hardware issue ).
Since your answer is great, but did not answered the original question I asked ( it is on hold )- I tought to open new Q and you'll answer it ?

Answer (score 1):

[chili555's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/943158/618353) is great, but only addresses the second of the two questions you ask, that is:

> 2. How to disable the internal Wi-Fi?

I'm adding this answer to address your first question:

> 1. Why can't I change the permissions of that file?

The reason you're not able to change the permissions of the `install.sh` file and some other files, as shown in your screenshot, is that you used the `+X` flag of `chmod`, instead of the `+x` one. The difference between the two flags is that `x` (lowercase "x") will set execution permissions for the specified files and directories, whereas `X` (uppercase "x") will set the permissions **only for directories or files that already have execution permissions**.

This is also stated in [`chmod`'s manpage](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man1/chmod.1.html), which you can access by running `man chmod` in your terminal. Here is the relevant part:

```
[...]
The letters rwxXst select file mode bits for the affected users: read (r),
write (w), execute (or search for directories) (x), execute/search only if the
file  is  a directory or already has execute permission for some user (X), [...]
```

Since your `install.sh` file does not already have execution rights, running `chmod +X install.sh` does nothing on it. If, instead, you had used:

```
chmod +x install.sh
```

then you would have given execution rights to `install.sh`, as you would expect.