# Edimax usb wifi (ew-7811un) not connecting on 17.04

Tags: 17.04

I just downloaded Ubuntu and am trying to get my WiFi set up.
I tried researching this but could not find anything for 17.04.

When I put it into the USB drive, it popped right up showing available networks. It tried to connect for a minute and then says disconnected. I just connected on another laptop so I know there's not an issue with the connection or my password...

Do I need to download/install any drivers even though it was immediately showing my wifi network?

I ran network diagnostics and here are the results: http://paste.ubuntu.com/25343050/

Comment: Make sure power management is disabled for this wireless device (check with `iwconfig` command), and make sure that your router is set for WPA2-AES.

Comment: same -
[link to answered question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/943145/ubuntu-how-to-disable-internal-wifi-hardware-and-use-usb-wifi) . solved by same @chilli555

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please check to see if two possibly conflicting drivers are loaded:

```
lsmod | grep rtl
```

If you find that both rtl8192cu and rtl8xxxu are loaded, then blacklist one:

```
sudo -i
echo "blacklist rtl8192cu"  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
exit
```

You will also need a change to Network Manager:

```
sudo nano /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
```

Add a new section as follows:

```
[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
```

Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor.

After making these changes, reboot and let us hear the result.

Comment: I ran the "lsmod | grep rtl" command, and it seems like something funny is going on. Here is the yield:    "~$ lsmod | grep rtl
rtl8xxxu              126976  0
rtl8192cu              65536  0
rtl_usb                20480  1 rtl8192cu
rtl8192c_common        49152  1 rtl8192cu
rtlwifi                73728  3 rtl_usb,rtl8192c_common,rtl8192cu
mac80211              782336  4 rtl_usb,rtlwifi,rtl8192cu,rtl8xxxu
cfg80211              602112  2 mac80211,rtlwifi"

Comment: You have found that both are loaded and conflicting. Please proceed.

Comment: Sorry I am still very new to linux, and am having trouble understanding how  to add a new section in network manager. I have the manager opened up and I have entered the following: "[Realtek RTL8188CUS]wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no ", but I don't understand the menu controls that are listed on the bottom of the command prompt(which one I need to select and how to select them. I'm not sure how I am supposed to enter "^X" for exit, as an example...

Comment: NO! It is exactly as I wrote it. `[device]` and then on the next line down: `wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no` You enter ^X with Ctrl+x. Before you do that, however, be sure to Write Out, meaning to save, the change you made with ^O, entered as Ctrl+o.

Comment: IT WORKED! Thanks man you are awesome. I wish I had your computer knowledge...maybe someday lol

Comment: If my answer was helpful, please accept it: https://askubuntu.com/tour

Comment: Hi chilli, it seems your answer here is the same as [another you posted earlier this month](https://askubuntu.com/questions/943145/chmod-x-does-not-succeed-ubuntu/943158#943158).  Is there a reason these questions should not be marked as duplicates to better organize the information?  I realize wireless/networking questions are not as simple as most other Qs we get, hence the question.

Comment: Is it correct to mark as a duplicate an answer that was not accepted?

Comment: I know I'm new around here, but I am not to web forums. My .02 is that this is not a duplicate. I searched for my exact question before asking it here, and nothing came up. Anyone who is  having a similar issue with this wifi adapter is going to have trouble finding that thread Seth linked, if they enter their issue into search.